# How do I load my ES6 classes into Jasmine specs?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Client.js

```
"use strict";

class Client {

}


describe("Client", function() {
  require('../client');

  beforeEach(function() {
    client = new Client();
  });

  it("should have a foo", function() {
    expect(client.foo).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Jasmine Can't find the class `Client`. How do I load my classes?

Comment: Is this code in a single file? Could your problem be just a simple extra `.` as in `require('../client')` instead of `require('./client')`?

Comment: A `require` is not an `include` that substitutes that whole file at the call site and puts all declarations in that scope. JS modules need to export something, and `require` is just a function call that *returns* that thing.